# Mysql count rows function

Tags: mysql, function

I have created a simple function which takes user id and show total no. of post by the user id

```
function totalpost($user_id){
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE u_id='.$user_id;
$total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) or die(mysql_errno());
return $total;
```

}

Its working fine, but when 0 record found, it not returns anything.

I want to return 0 if there are no record found

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function totalpost($user_id){
  $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE u_id='.intval($user_id);
  $res = mysql_query($sql)) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  return $row[0];
}
```

not because you need 0, but because you have to always use `count()` instead of selectiong all users posts which can be big load of data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE u_id=xx
```

By using the `COUNT` function you will guarantee a 0 will be returned even if no rows match the `WHERE` clause.